# How to define and reuse list of columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

As the title says it, I have a huge table with a lot of columns, I need only like half or more of them (this is not the point). The point is I don't want to use `*` because I am getting too many and is taking a little more time than wanted.

I want to basically write a few **UNION** and writing all columns every time is taking a lot of space and looks messy. Instead what I am looking for is to declare a list of column names and simply reuse it in each **SELECT** statement if this is possible.

```
SELECT col1, col2, ... col_n FROM mytbl
UNION
SELECT col1, col2, ... col_n FROM mytbl
UNION
SELECT col1, col2, ... col_n FROM mytbl
UNION
SELECT col1, col2, ... col_n FROM mytbl
```

I want to get something like

```
columns_to_extract = [col1, col2, ... col_n]
SELECT columns_to_extract FROM mytbl
UNION
SELECT columns_to_extract FROM mytbl
UNION
SELECT columns_to_extract FROM mytbl
UNION
SELECT columns_to_extract FROM mytbl
```

Answer (score 1):

Use some client-specific feature for that.

For example for `psql` client:

```
\set foobar 'aid, bid'
select :foobar from pgbench_accounts
    union all
select :foobar from pgbench_accounts;
```